# exporting php Data to excel starting with 0

Tags: php, excel

I want to export my php Data to excel.

But I am facing an issue

Values in a column start with something like '00003421' in php but when it is exported in excel, it shows only '3421' in the cell. It ignores the zero values. Moreover, I want them in text data type.

How can I export the data in plain text format as it is (including zeroes)?

I have tried starting with single quote like this `'00032` but its showing in the excel as well with single quote
It's tabular data with 32 columns and around 20,000 rows.
Any way to resolve this ?

Comment: I mean you can convert data in Excel, after it exported

Comment: I want to export data to excel from php for the columns which has value starting with 0 but now its only showing ```122``` instead of ```00123```

Comment: My best guess is that you're exporting a CSV file. Is that correct?

Comment: You need to show the exact code you're using for this. If you're exporting direct to Excel I would expect that whatever library you're using could set the data type of the columns / rows / cells you're writing to. But if you're writing to CSV, then if you inspect the raw data of the CSV in a text file I expect you'll find the the data is correct in there, and the problem actually would come due to using the wrong configuration to import into Excel.

Comment: No I'm exporting the data in an Excel file which is getting created from PHP Excel

Comment: PHP Excel was deprecated in 2017. Why not switch to [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)?

Comment: In my experience you may solve this problem by adding `style='mso-number-format:"\@";'` to the excel cell